# Как вывести innerHTML не в один а в несколько одинаковых div?

Tags: javascript

```js
guide = document.querySelector('.guide');
icon = document.querySelector('.nm');

str = guide.innerHTML;

icon.innerHTML = str.substring(0, 2);
```

```html
<article class="rd-guides">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p class="nm"></p>
      <p class="guide">Alica Crewer</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="nm"></p>
      <p class="guide">Brad Morison</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="nm"></p>
      <p class="guide">Oleg Bykovis</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

Знаете в мессенджерах, если у абонента нет аватарки, выводится первые буквы имени и фамилии (или, что указано). Я же просто вывожу в `div` первые две буквы, с которых начинается слово. Мне нужно, что бы отображалось в нескольких `div`. В моем случае - в трех. Выводится только в первый. Как вывести во все которые имеют одинаковый класс?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
/*
document.querySelectorAll('.rd-guides li').forEach(item => {
  item.querySelector(".nm").textContent = 
    item.querySelector(".guide").textContent.substring(0, 2);
});
*/

// find all li-s inside .rd-guides
var listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.rd-guides li');
for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
  // for each item
  var item = listItems[i];
  // find .guide and .nm inside it
  var nm = item.querySelector(".nm");
  var guide = item.querySelector(".guide");
  // set text inside nm
  nm.textContent = guide.textContent.substring(0, 2);
}
```

```html
<article class="rd-guides">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <p class="nm"></p>
      <p class="guide">Alica Crewer</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="nm"></p>
      <p class="guide">Brad Morison</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="nm"></p>
      <p class="guide">Oleg Bykovis</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое

Comment: @Ученик Пожалуйста. Успехов!